# Excel vba extract top 5 google search results URL in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have below VBA code which is working fine for getting first result URL, But I want it to modify to get top 5 Results URL.

I'm trying for hours but not able to find out what to do :(

any help would be appreciated greatly.

```
Sub XMLHTTP()

Dim URL As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 2 To lastRow

    URL = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
    Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(0)
    Set link = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)

    str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")
    Cells(i, 2) = str_text
    Cells(i, 3) = link.href
    DoEvents
Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)End Sub
```

I have no VBA expertise but In my Last Attempt I try to do this and getting same link in all results

```
Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(0)
    Set link = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)

    str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")
    Cells(i, 2) = str_text
    Cells(i, 3) = link.href
    Set link2 = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    str_text = Replace(link2.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    Cells(i, 4) = link2.href
    Set link3 = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    str_text = Replace(link3.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    Cells(i, 5) = link3.href
    Set link4 = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    str_text = Replace(link4.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    Cells(i, 6) = link4.href
```

Comment: So you're 'trying for hours' to write a loop that changes the **0** in .getElementsByTagName("H3")(0) from 0 to 4? Please [edit] your question to include your last attempt.

Comment: I have updated it please have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Thank you Jeeped for pointing me into the right direction.

```html
Sub XMLHTTP()

Dim URL As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 2 To lastRow

    URL = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
    Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(0)
    Set link = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)

    str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")
    Cells(i, 2) = link.href
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(1)
    Set link = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")
    Cells(i, 3) = link.href
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(2)
    Set link = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")
    Cells(i, 4) = link.href
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(3)
    Set link = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")
    Cells(i, 5) = link.href
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(4)
    Set link = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")
    Cells(i, 6) = link.href
    
    DoEvents
Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

thank you